# Is $\| B(AB)^\dagger \|_2 $ uniformly bounded for all positive diagonal matrices $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, pseudoinverse, regularization

Consider $\| B(AB)^\dagger \|_2$ where $A$ is a real matrix, $B$ is a real, square and symmetric matrix, and $(AB)^\dagger$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of $AB$. Is $\| B(AB)^\dagger \|_2$ uniformly bounded over all non-singular symmetric matrices $B$? If not, what about over all positive diagonal matrices $B$?

For example, when $A$ and $B$ are both non-singular, $\| B(AB)^\dagger \|_2 = \| A^{-1} \|_2 $, and the norm of interest is uniformly bounded for all $B$. My question is about whether a similar result exists for when $A$ is not invertible. Some relevant references would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your first question is "no". Consider e.g.
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0},\ B=\pmatrix{1&t\\ t&t}
$$
where $0<t<1$. Then
$$
B(AB)^+
=\pmatrix{1&t\\ t&t}\pmatrix{t&t\\ 0&0}^+
=\pmatrix{1&t\\ t&t}\pmatrix{\frac12t^{-1}&0\\ \frac12t^{-1}&0}
=\pmatrix{\frac12(t^{-1}+1)&0\\ 1&0},
$$
whose norm is not bounded above.

Comment: Good example. I do think it is uniformly bounded over all positive diagonal matrices. Do you have any suggestions here?